# Regex filtering list of words

Tags: regex, filter

I need a simple regex but I cant make by my own. I try different ways with no luck

I have a list of words that I need to exclude from my text
xej.

```
Text=Hoy es un dia soleado y mañana las nubes no estaran y los pajaros tampoco
```

List of words that I will filter from Text: `y`, `es`, `Es`, `ES`, `un`, `UN`, `Un`, `las`, `los`, `la`, `lo`, etc

So, the resulting Text will be:

```
Hoy dia soleado mañana nubes estaran pajaros tampoco
```

Those words it will be a filter list that I need to filter from my texts.

I tried something like this:

```
(?![Ll][aAoO][sS]*\b|[Ee]?[Ll]\b])[\w]+
```

So I can filter with:

`?![Ll][aAoO][sS]*\b` the words `Las`, `Los`, `las`, `la`, `lo`

`[Ee]?[Ll]\b]` the words `el`, `El`, `EL`, `eL`

But if i apply that regex the letter L and l are not filtered.

How can I make this regex?

Comment: What is the language/tool that you are using the regex in?

Comment: I am using this http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Perhaps something like `(y|es|Es|...)` would do the trick? (would need a component to stop it matching parts of words)

Comment: @user2088434: The actual tool, not the regex tester!

Answer (score 1):

```
s/\b(y|es|Es|ES|un|UN|Un|las|los|la|lo)\b//g
```

Explanation:

`\b` is a word boundary. It looks for places where words break, but doesn't actually select anything.

Comment: Ok, but I need to filter those words how can I do it with a regex? So if I apply  the regex only the other words are selected